# How do I transfer altcoins from cryptsy to bittrex?

Tags: exchanges, altcoin

How do i transfer altcoins from cryptsy to bittrex?

Bittrex says this if i open generate the deposit address -

```
When depositing, please send your message unencrypted.

If the message is not included in your transfer, we cannot credit your account. 
Please do not directly deposit from an exchange or pool unless they allow 
you to specify a message.
```

I don't see any place to enter the message.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What specific altcoin are you trying to transfer?

Comment: trying to move some NAUT and DGB